# Scale a number but ensure it is greater than a value

Tags: ratio, image-processing

I have a grid with a Y-axis with a minimum of 25, and a maximum of 50 but the scale begins at 25 (25-50) and a X-axis with a minimum of 0, and a maximum of 4 that begins at 0 (0-4)

I have a set of coordinates (X&Y) and they must not exceed the max values

```
x,y
--------------
0,25

0,52
```

The max Y is 50 so I tried to create a scale `50/52=0.96`

`25*0.96=24`
`52*0.96=49.92`

So now my coordinates become

```
x,y
--------------
0,24

0,49.92
```

24<25 so this won't work. How can I scale these numbers but ensure they are greater than 25?

Comment: 25+(factor scaled and then sacaled)

Comment: @LuisFelipe Sorry I'm not too good at math could you send a formula with numbers?

Comment: A question about your "set of coordinates": What are these values? Min(x), Max(x), Min(y) and Max(y)

Comment: Sorry what is the question? If you are asking what they are for it's for a software program that draws on a coordinate grid. Min(x)=0, Max(x)=4, Min(y)=25, Max(y)=50

Comment: I am not asking about your grid. I am asking about your data. You cited an example where the value of y is 52. Hence Max(y) >= 52. Understood?

Comment: No sorry my English is not the best. I need to scale all values so they don't exceed 50. But I have to scale all values equally hence why I am asking how to scale and ensure Min Y >= 25 in my example above the way I am doing it the value becomes 24 which is > than 25

Comment: y could be as large as 52, correct? Do you know how big/small values you are handling (both for x and y)? If you know these 4 numbers, your problem is probably easy to solve.

Comment: No y max is 50 so it cannot be 52. Yes the numbers for x and y are above in the table in the original post. My two y values are 25 and 52. Both numbers have 5o be above 25 but below 50. I am trying to come up with a formula/algorithm to do this for me no matter how large or small the number is so that it is always above 25 and below 50.

Answer (score 1):

I think (maybe) you want to transform the $x$-range $0$ to $25$ so it evenly covers the range $25$ to $50$, and you want to transform the $y$-range $0$ to $52$ so it evenly covers the range $0$ to $50$.

The $x$-range is easy, just add $25$, because the two ranges are equal in size. For the $y$-range, $0$ to $52$ is too big by a factor of $52\over50$, so* multiply by $50\over52$. *You don’t need to add or subtract anything before or after you multiply, since the range starts at $0$ and you still want it to start at $0$.

In general, if you have $x$ in the range $a$ to $b$ and you want a transformed $x'$ to be in the range $c$ to $d$, change $x$ by first subtracting $a$, then multiplying by the width $d-c$ divided by the width $b-a$, then add $c$ to get the starting point right. So $x_new=(x-a)\cdot{d-c\over b-a} + c$. This assumes $a<b$ and $c<d$ and you don’t need to reverse the direction of the range.